# Looking to compare values in two different files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two CSV files that have been renamed to text files. I need to compare a column in each one (a date) to confirm they have been updated.

For example, `c:\temp\oldfile.txt` has 6 columns and the last one is called `version`. I need to make sure that `c:\temp\newfile.txt` has a different value for `version`. It doesn't need to do any date verification of any kind, as long as the comparison sees that they're different, it can proceed. If possible, I would prefer to stick with 'standard' libraries as I'm just learning and don't want to start creating dictionaries and learning pandas and numpy just yet.

**Edit**

Here's a copy of `oldfile.txt` and `newfile.txt`.

`oldfile.txt`:

```
feed_publisher_name,feed_publisher_url,feed_lang,feed_start_date,feed_end_date,feed_version
MyStuff,http://www.mystuff.com,en,20220103,20220417,22APR_20220401
```

`newfile.txt`:

```
feed_publisher_name,feed_publisher_url,feed_lang,feed_start_date,feed_end_date,feed_version
MyStuff,http://www.mystuff.com,en,20220103,20220417,22APR_20220414
```

In this case the comparison would note that the last column has a different value and would know to proceed with the rest of the script. Otherwise, if the values are the same, it will know that it was not updated and I'll have the program exit.

Comment: You could provide some data and the corresponding output you want.

Comment: why you don't just show an example of both txt. files instead of describing it? Easier for you and easier for the readers. And what do mean by proceed if verfificated ? just a print statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module in the standard library since that's the format of your files.

```
import csv

with open('oldfile.txt', 'r', newline='') as oldfile, \
     open('newfile.txt', 'r', newline='') as newfile:

    old_reader = csv.DictReader(oldfile)
    new_reader = csv.DictReader(newfile)

    old_row = next(old_reader)
    new_row = next(new_reader)

    same = old_row['feed_version'] == new_row['feed_version']
    print(f"The files are {'the same' if same else 'different'}.")
```

Comment: Straightforward, works, and I learned a little bit, against my will ;-) I wasn't sure if the CSV library would work because they were text files, but this worked great. Thank you very much!

Comment: That's good to hear, I was trying to be gentle and not expose you to any fancy modules. The `csv` module doesn't care what extension a file has, as long as its *contents* are text characters.

Answer (score 1):

**Reading the file-**
we don't need any libraries for this. just opening the file and reading it, then doing a little parsing:

```py
a, b = "", "" # set the globals for the comparison

with open("c:/temp/oldfile.txt") as f: # open the file as f
    text = f.read().split('\n')[1] # get the contents of the file then cut just the second line from it
    a = text.split(',')[5] # spliting the string by ',' to an array then getting the 6th element
```

Then opening the other one:

```py
with open("c:/temp/newfile.txt") as f:
    text = f.read().split('\n')[1]
    b = text.split(',')[5]
```

more on reading files [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/)

**Comparing the lines-**

```py
if a == b:
    print("The date is the same!")
else:
    print("The date is different...")
```

Of course you can make this into a function and make it return whether or not they're equal then use the value to determine the future of the program.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think your solution will work best for what I want to do. I had to use double backslashes i.e. c:\\temp\\oldfile.txt, but a little sleuthing is good for learning. The only thing I've found is that it is reading the column name, not the value below it. So in the example I added, if the date changes from 22APR_20220401 to 22APR_20220414, it doesn't detect it. But if I change the column name from feed_version to feed_version_123, it notices the change.

Comment: totally forgot about those, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in checking if there two files are the equal (essentially "updated"), you can compute the hash of one file and compare with the hash of the other

To compute hash (for example, sha256), you can use the following function:

```
import hashlib
def sha256sum(filename):
    # Opens the file
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        content = file.read()
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()
    hasher.update(content)
    return hasher.hexdigest()
```

[hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) is probably part of the standard library if you went through the default installation process.

For example, if you write "v1.0" in a text document, the hasher function will give "fa8b919c909d5eb9e373d090928170eb0e7936ac20ccf413332b96520903168e"

If you later change it to "v1.1", the hasher function will give "eb79768c42dbbf9f10733e525a06ea9eb08f28b7b8edf9c6dcacb63940aedcb0".

These are two different hexdigest values, so it would imply that two files are different.

Comment: That's a great idea and I'll give it a go once we have a stablized version. Very useful!!